# Multiple NIC same subnet

Tags: iptables, router, linux-networking, subnet

I have a setup as shown in the image. I know it is insane but i have to work on this configuration only.

It is basically an **ubuntu server acting as a router** with 4 interfaces. 3 of them (eth0, eth1 and eth3) act as gateways to PC1, PC2 and PC3 respectively.

I want the PCs access internet through them and set iptable rules to build a firewall on the ubuntu server.

---

```
                              -----
                             | PC1 |10.1.0.101/16 (gw & dns-10.1.0.20)
                              ----- 
                                |
                           eth1 |10.1.0.20/16
                         ---------------
                        |               |
                   eth0 |    Ubuntu     | eth2         ----- 
10.1.5.244 -------------|    Server     |-------------| PC2 |10.1.0.102/16
(Router)    10.1.0.10/16|               |10.1.0.30/16  ----- (gw & dns-10.1.0.30)
                         ---------------            
                           eth3 |10.1.0.40/16
                                |
                              -----
                             | PC3 |10.1.0.103/16
                              ----- (gw & dns-10.1.0.40)

eth0 - connected to router (internet connected interface - gw=10.1.5.244)
       inet addr:10.1.0.10  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
eth1 - inet addr:10.1.0.20  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
eth2 - inet addr:10.1.0.30  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0
eth3 - inet addr:10.1.0.40  Bcast:10.1.255.255  Mask:255.255.0.0

$route -n 
Destination     Gateway         Genmask         Flags Metric Ref    Use Iface
default         10.1.5.244      0.0.0.0         UG    0      0        0 eth0
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth2
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth1
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth3
10.1.0.0        *               255.255.0.0     U     0      0        0 eth0
```

I have solved the ARP flux problem with following arp configurations.

```
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_filter
echo "1" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_ignore
echo "2" > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/arp_announce
```

Also i have setup ip routes on 3 interfaces eth1, eth2 and eth3 as shown below for eth2.

```
echo "152 table2" >>/etc/iproute2/rt_tables
ip route add default via 10.1.0.10 dev eth0 table table2
ip route add 10.1.0.0/16 dev eth2 table table2
ip rule add from 10.1.0.30 table table2
ip rule add to 10.1.0.30 table table2
```

**I am not sure about IP rules on eth0.**

with above configuration i am able to connect to individual interfaces eth1, eth2, eth3 with PC1, PC2 and PC3 (resolving arp flux issue).

However i am not able to connect to the internet on PC1 and PC3.

*It seems that the returning packets are routed to eth2 only (1st entry in route -n for 10.1.0.0/16 subnet) regardless of originating PC1, PC2 or PC3.*
*(Also I have kept **rp_filter=1** as I want to use corresponding outgoing interface only.)*

**So my question is how to route return packets to corresponding interface or how to access internet on the PCs from corresponding interface only.**

Comment: A router routes between different networks, not on the same network. I think you mean a bridge.

Comment: Yes. As noted in the question, my intention is to filter traffic based on the interface it is coming from.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you are trying to force a router to do a switch's job... but why not turn the server into an actual switch ?

You can use the network bridge solution in Ubuntu to just bridge all the interfaces, and then you would use the server as a transparent firewall, without any layer 3 interfaces involved in traffic from the PCs to the Internet.

See here : https://help.ubuntu.com/community/NetworkConnectionBridge

Alternatively, make it an actual router, but in that case split your /16 into smaller subnets such that each PC is on its own subnet, and then have a final subnet between the server and the Internet gateway.

Answer (score 0):

Linux Netfilter is capable of passing bridged traffice into iptables rule tables for checking. There are special expressions to match against specific physical interface (because logical interface you specify in -i or -o will always be bridge interface in this case).

To enable this feature you have to set up these sysctl variables as needed (in `sysctl.conf`, some file in `sysctl.conf.d`, echoing 1 into some file in /proc etc.):

```
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-arptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-iptables = 1
net.bridge.bridge-nf-call-ip6tables = 1
```

Meaning of each option is self-explaining. These keys appear only after `bridge` kernel module is loaded, for example, with `modprobe bridge`.

Then build a usual bridge:

```
auto eth0
iface eth0 inet manual

auto eth1
iface eth1 inet manual

auto eth2
iface eth3 inet manual

auto br0
iface br0 inet static
    address 10.1.0.10
    netmask 255.255.0.0
    broadcast 10.1.255.255
    network 10.1.0.0
    bridge_ports eth0 eth1 eth2
    bridge_stp off
    bridge_fd 0
```

Note you don't need to have multiple IP addresses of the router. Bridge is like a very smart switch.

After that, you may filter your traffic using physdev module:

```
iptables -A FILTER -m physdev --physdev-in eth0 -s 10.0.1.2 -j DROP
```

this example rule will drop any traffic from 10.0.1.2 which enters router through eth0.

Use `iptables -m physdev --help` to see all its capabilities.

There are also other features in Netfilter designed specifically for dealing of bridge traffic. These features are uncovered with another userspace utility called `ebtables`. They allow for, for example, MAC address masquerading and translation, brouting and so on; read ebtables manual for details.